# How to add AppImages to Taskbar and Applications list

Tags: .desktop, taskbar, appimage

I have downloaded a few App Images that work better than their electron counterpart- however, I would like to add them to my list of applications that can be accessed from `Show Applications`. I would also like to add to favorite for easy access from the task bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To include any application in your applications menu, create a `.desktop` launcher in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory. Once it appears in your menu, you can pin it from there in your favorites. `~` is a shorthand for the path of your home directory, e.g. `/home/user`.

A `.desktop` launcher is nothing more than a plain text file with a `.desktop extension. A valid launcher contains at least the` Name=`,` Exec=`, and` Type=` lines, for example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Avidemux
Exec=/home/vanadium/.appimage/avidemux_2.8.0.appImage %f
Type=Application
```

The name is what is shown in the application overview. The `Exec=` line must point to a valid executable, or the launcher will not show up. `Type=application` tells the system this is a reference to an application, not to an URI.

A fancier version at least specifies also an icon. An generic name adds search terms for the menu.

You can specify a full pathname to an icon file, but a better practice is to place it in your `~/.local/share/icons` folder. Make that folder if you do not have it. Then the icon will be found just by its file name, without extension. For example, if you stored the icon as `~/.local/share/icons/avidemux.png`, then the `Icon=` line simply ca read `Icon=avidemux`.

An example of a more fatty version of the `.desktop` launcher above is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Avidemux
GenericName=Video Editor
Comment=Multiplatform video editor
Exec=/home/vanadium/.appimage/avidemux_2.8.0.appImage %f
Icon=avidemux
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;AudioVideoEditing;Video;
MimeType=video/mpeg;video/x-mpeg;video/mp4;video/x-m4v;video/quicktime;video/3gp;video/mkv;video/x-matroska;video/webm;video/flv;video/x-flv;video/dv;video/x-msvideo;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-anim;
```

**Tip specific for appimages**: appimages typically contain a sample desktop file and icons. That can save you typing and searching on the internet.

- Run the appimage
- In a terminal, find out where the appimage is mounted from the output of the command 'mount'.

  ```
  $ mount
  ...
  avidemux_2.8.0.appImage on /tmp/.mount_avidem5jL4TC type fuse.avidemux_2.8.0.appImage (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
  ```
- With your file manager, take a look in the mounted folder (`/tmp/.mount_avidem5jL4TC`, and see whether there is an icon and a `.desktop` file you can use. Edit the `.desktop` file so it points to the actual appimage file.